# PostgreSQL. Create table. Field type problem

Tags: postgresql

```
// xml file
...
<DateBegin>06.2007</DateBegin>
...

// sql file
CREATE TABLE goods (
  ...
  begin_of_production undefined_type,
  ...
);
```

I get data from xml file for goods table. Date format in xml file: 'mm.yyyy'. How do I define type of the begin_of_production field for this date format?

I found date formats with day in PostgreSQL doc. Example: 'yyyy.mm.dd'. But for my table these formats are bad way, because the day is undefined in the xml file.

Comment: Depends what data-type (int, text, etc.) will be inserted in that column, but since it's called _'begin_of_production'_, I guess it could be a timestamp (with or without timezone) -> see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype.html for more on data-types in pgsql. Also keep NOT_NULL constraints in mind..

Comment: Assuming the column `begin_of_production` is sourced from the XML <DateBegin>...</DateBegin> after extraction, your value appear to contain *month.year*. If so then data type for it is `DATE` and  the for value  just use the expression `to_date(DateBegin, 'mm.yyyy')` again **after DateBegin  value extracted from the xml**.